# Import Error when running task on python anywhere

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a task to run daily using PythonAnywhere and keep getting the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/10Cents/10-cents-app/Django/10cents/webdesign/cent/tasks.py", line 3, in 
>       from . import views
>   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

[image: file structure]

Comment: How are you running you code? To use relative imports, you must be using a package, which are run by passing the module's Python path via the `-m` flag of the interpreter.

Comment: Take a look at PythonAnywhere help page about that https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/